# How to prove closure of unit ball in Banach-Alaoglu theorem?

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, banach-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

I am studying the proof of the Banach–Alaoglu theorem in V. Moretti's *Spectral Theory and Quantum Mechanics*, and it seems an important step in the proof was omitted. (In fact, I think the omitted step is significant enough to render the proof incomplete without it.)

Let $X$ be a normed space over $\mathbb C$, $X'$ its topological dual (the space of bounded linear functionals on $X$), and define the following sets:

$B_x=\{c\in\mathbb C:|c|\leqslant\|x\|\}$

$P=\prod_{x\in X}B_x$, equipped with the product topology

$B=\{f\in X':\|f\|\leqslant1\}$

The theorem states that $B$ is compact in the *-weak topology on $X'$, and part of the proof relies on $B$ being closed in the product topology on $P$. But the proof only shows *sequential closure* of $B$, that is, that $B\ni p_n\to p\in P$ as $n\to\infty$ in the product topology on $P$ implies $p\in B$. But not all sequentially closed sets are closed, except in the special case of [sequential spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space).

Unfortunately, there is even an additional lapse in the proof of sequential closure. The proof claims $p$ is linear because, for any $a, b \in \mathbb C$, $x, y \in X:$

$$p(ax+by)=\lim_{n\to\infty}p_n(ax+by) = a \lim_{n\to\infty}p_n(x) + b\lim_{n\to\infty}p_n(y)=ap(x) + bp(y).$$

The second $=$ sign above is justified only if we already know that $p_n(x)$ and $p_n(y)$ converge for any $x,y \in X$, that is, if $(p_n)$ converges in the *-weak topology. But we are only given that $(p_n)$ converges in the product topology on $P$.

**How can these two flaws be remedied? In particular,**

**1. How can we show that $P$ with the product topology is sequential?**

**2. How can we justify the second $=$ sign mentioned above?**

---

I would be fine with, instead of answers to (1) and (2), taking a different strategy to correct the flaws mentioned. However, please avoid using nets, as I am not familiar with them and am curious to see how this proof can be accomplished without them.

Comment: How is $X'$ defined?

Comment: It is the topological dual of $X$, i.e., the set of bounded linear functionals on $X$.

Comment: I just updated the post to clarify this notation for $X'$

Comment: Will, I suggest you study nets because they are not so different from sequences and they often greatly simplify certain proofs.  Once you get a hang of nets it is almost as if all spaces are sequencial!

Comment: $P$ is not sequencial in the product topology.

Comment: @Ruy So the proof in the book is just wrong. I am sure that nets make this proof easier, but it is also nice to see how it can be done without them.

Comment: I guess one cannot say for sure that Moretti made a mistake in that proof because he did not use the word **sequence** there.  If you take the statement "Suppose, then, $B\ni p_n \to p \in P$ as $n \to+\infty$" to mean "let $\{p_n\}_n$ be a **net** converging to $p$", and I think this interpretation is quite plausible, then the proof would be OK.  However, since  nets are not explicitly mentioned anywhere in the book,  you are justified in suspecting that he was indeed thinking about sequences!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$B$ is closed because its complement in $X'$  is the union of   $\{f\in X': |f(x)| >1\}$ over all vectors $x$ with $\|x\| \leq 1$. The set $\{f\in X': |f(x)| >1\}$ is open in the product topology restricted to $X'$ and union of open sets is open. The fact that $X'$ is closed in $P$ follows from the argument below. Hence the complement in $P$ is also open.

For the second question here is a hint: $\{p\in P: p(ax+by)-ap(x)-bp(y)\neq 0\}$ is open in the product topology.

Comment: @WillG Sorry , there was a typo.

Comment: Sorry, could you clarify when you are considering $X'$ as the total space vs $P$? Namely, for complements and for the set $\{f:|f(x)|>1\}$.

Comment: @WillG I hope the answer is clear now.

Comment: @WillG  Incidentally both parts of your question have one line answers if you are familiar with nets.

Comment: Fair enough, but I think it is also helpful to see how this can be done without nets.

Comment: To fill in the blanks on part 2: We must show that $P\setminus X'$ is open. Let $f \in P\setminus X'$. Then $f$ cannot be linear, for otherwise the definition of $P$ implies that $f$ is also bounded, and so we would have $f \in X'$. Thus there exist some $a, b \in \mathbb C, x, y \in X$, such that $f(ax + by) \neq af(x) + bf(y)$. Letting $z = ax + by$ and $c = af(x) + bf(y)$, we have $f \in U := \{ p ∈ P : p(z) \in \mathbb C\setminus\{c\} \}$, where $U \subseteq P$ is open in the product topology since $\mathbb C\setminus\{c\}$ is open in $\mathbb C$.